# MS Project Add-In Programming in .Net

Tags: .net, add-in, ms-project

We are building an Add-in for MS project and relatively new to the Office SDK programming. Any tips, guidelines, links for MS Project Add-In programming would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what version of Project you are targeting.

Here are two places to start for 2010 and 2007.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee767697.aspx
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472154(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472154%28v=office.12%29.aspx)